# How to call a function's methods from within another function

Tags: javascript, methods, scope, call

In the `form` object below, from within the "check" function, how do I call the "show" and "hide" methods of the notification function?

```
(function (namespace, $, undefined) {
    var form = {
        check : function(){
            form.notification.show(); // Generates an error
        },

        notification : function(){
            this.show = function(){
                ...
            };
            this.hide = function(){
                ...
            };
        }
    };
}(window.namespace = window.namespace || {}, jQuery));
```

With `form.notification.show()` I get the following error:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define `notification` outside `form` and then refer to it:

```
var notification : { // no function here
        show : function(){...}, // avoid "this"
        hide : function(){...}
};

var form = {
    check : function(){
        notification.show(); // <-- Use here
    },

    notification : notification // and here
};
```

(I omitted the `jQuery` protection code for clarity).

The next problem is that you `this.show =` will assign the function to whatever `this` is when the function `notification()` is executed. `this` isn't `notification`!

Comment: Strange - this doesn't appear to have any effect. I'm wondering now if there's a conflict in my "working" code...

Comment: Well, it seems that I *do* have access to the notification function in my original code. If I run `console.log(form.notification)` from within the check function, it returns the script. Any thoughts?

Comment: See my edits. `show` is put into `this` and `this !== form.notification` (most likely).

Comment: You're right - `this` referred to the form object. Making `notification` an object seems to be the obvious fix.

Comment: I've improved my answer again. If it solves your problem now, please accept it.

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar - albeit slightly more succinct - and kept the notification object inside the form object.

Answer (score 0):

You've enclosed it, so you need to return it and that will expose it for you, if you whip the following in chrome console, you'll see you have access to the form object

```
(function (namespace, $, undefined) {

var form = {

        check : function(){
            form.notification.show(); // Generates an error
        },

        notification : function(){
            this.show = function(){

            };
            this.hide = function(){

            };
        }


};
return{form:form};}(window.namespace = window.namespace || {}, jQuery));
```

All i've done to your code is added

```
return{form:form};
```

After the form object. Hope this helps

**EDIT**

If you want to only expose certain parts of the form, for example only notifications, you could modify the return like so:

```
return{form.notification: notification}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure why it was downvoted either. However, this isn't a viable option as nothing may follow the return statement.

Comment: Not true copy the above code and paste it into your console. then type in window.namespace and see what it returns.

Comment: I downvoted it because at that point the answer was just a block of code with no explanation.  Also, it's _almost always_ a bad idea to reference an object by its external name from within that object - in most cases it should be accessible as `this`.